# RxJS Operator to delay handling subsequent events

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm looking for an RxJS operator (or a combination of operators) which will allow me to achieve this:

1. Every event fired by the observable should be handled by the order it was triggered (no skipping, throttling, debouncing any of the values).
2. I should be abled to define a set interval between the handling of 2 subsequent events.
3. In case no previous events are currently handled, the next event should be handled immediately (no delay).

I created the [following example](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-q-gdi0d?file=/src/app/app.component.html) which I hope will make this clearer:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { delay } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  counter = 1;
  displayedValue = 1;

  valueEmitter = new Subject<number>();
  valueEmitted$ = this.valueEmitter.asObservable();

  ngOnInit() {
    // I want to allow each incremented value to be displayed for at least 2 seconds
    this.valueEmitted$.pipe(delay(2000)).subscribe((value) => {
      this.displayedValue = value;
    });
  }

  onClick() {
    const nextCounter = ++this.counter;
    this.counter = nextCounter;
    this.valueEmitter.next(nextCounter);
  }
}
```

In this example, I would like each value incremented in the `counter` to be shown as the `displayedValue` for at least 2 seconds.

So the first time the user clicks `onClick` the displayed value should immediately change from 1 to 2 but in case the user keeps on rapidly incrementing the `counter` the `displyedValue` should follow along in a delayed manner allowing each of the previously incremented numbers to be displayed for 2 seconds before changing, slowly catching up with the current counter value.

Can this be achieved with RxJs operators?

**UPDATE**

For the moment I came up with the [following solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-q-68414582-my-non-operator-solution-3z4q8?file=/src/app/app.component.ts):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  counter = 1;
  displayedValue = 1;
  currentDisplayedValueStartTime = 0;
  readonly DISPLAY_DURATION = 2000;
  valuesToDisplay = [];
  displayedValueSwitcherInterval: number | null = null;

  valueEmitter = new Subject<number>();
  valueEmitted$ = this.valueEmitter.asObservable();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.valueEmitted$.pipe().subscribe((value) => {
      this.handleValueDisplay(value);
    });
  }

  onClick() {
    const nextCounter = ++this.counter;
    this.counter = nextCounter;
    this.valueEmitter.next(nextCounter);
  }

  handleValueDisplay(value) {
    this.valuesToDisplay.push(value);

    if (!this.displayedValueSwitcherInterval) {
      this.displayedValue = this.valuesToDisplay.shift();

      this.displayedValueSwitcherInterval = window.setInterval(() => {
        const nextDiplayedValue = this.valuesToDisplay.shift();
        if (nextDiplayedValue) {
          this.displayedValue = nextDiplayedValue;
        } else {
          clearInterval(this.displayedValueSwitcherInterval);
          this.displayedValueSwitcherInterval = null;
        }
      }, this.DISPLAY_DURATION);
    }
  }
}
```

It's not what I was looking for since it relies on the component state and on `setInterval` in order to manage the notification queue. I was hoping to find something cleaner and more declarative which relies on RxJs operators to handle my notifications stream, and their interval queue - but at least I got the feature to work exactly as I wanted. Still open to suggestions on how to make this better.

Comment: Still not clear to me. Especially #3. GImme some concrete usecases.

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov - think of the clicks in the example as multiple responses returning from the server at once (or at very short intervals) and you want to display a 2 second snackbar-message for each one of them subsequently. 
#3 - you don't want to wait for 2 seconds before showing the first snackbar.
Did you check out the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-q-gdi0d?file=/src/app/app.component.html)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this could be a way to solve it:

```js
this.valueEmitted$
  .pipe(
    concatMap(
      (v) => concat(
        of(v),
        timer(2000).pipe(ignoreElements())
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe((value) => {
    this.displayedValue = value;
  });
```

Because `timer` also emits some values(0, 1, 2 and so forth), we use `ignoreElements` since we're not interested in those values and all we want from `timer` is the **complete notification** which will indicate the moment when the next inner observable can be subscribed. Note that the beforementioned inner observable is created by invoking the `concatMap`'s callback function with `v` as the argument.

*[Working demo.](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-q-68414582-forked-nqi22?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)*

---

> Every event fired by the observable should be handled by the order it was triggered (no skipping, throttling, debouncing any of the values).

This is ensured with the help of `concatMap`.

> I should be able to define a set interval between the handling of 2 subsequent events.

We can achieve that with:

```js
concat(
  // First, we send the value.
  of(v),
  // Then we set up a timer so that in case a new notification is emitted, it will have to
  // wait for the timer to end.
  timer(2000).pipe(ignoreElements())
)
```

> In case no previous events are currently handled, the next event should be handled immediately (no delay).

If there are no active inner observables created by `concatMap`, then the value `v` will be sent immediately to the consumer.

---

This would also work:

```js
this.valueEmitted$
  .pipe(
    concatMap(
      (v) => timer(2000).pipe(
        ignoreElements(), startWith(v)
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe((value) => {
    this.displayedValue = value;
  });
```

Comment: Wonderful! Looks like this is the solution I was looking for. Thanks. I think I like the second option even better - cleaner and more declarative, but both are great.

Answer (score 3):

So your comment made it a bit more clear.

Obviously, you need some state. Because you can't display everything at once, user's screen is not infinite. It can't handle more than.. 3.. 4.. 5 notification at once.

[scan](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan) is the way you handle state within the `rxjs` emitting each event.

Your `scan` may hold two lists: one for those notification which are currently rendered and the other one for pending notifications. Lists do preserve order as well as `scan` does, so ordering won't be violated.

Then you need to be able to act differently based on your events. The simplest thing I can imagine is tuple `(event_type_as_sting_or_number, event_specific_params)`. Having that you will be able to correctly compute your next state (which will be emitted by the `scan`) and then handle it gracefully (like rerender notifications).

Seems you need three events:

1. New event has came from the outer space.
2. Some notification has expired and must be taken off the screen.
3. User acked some notification and it does not make any sens to keep it.

So the entire pipeline is: `merge` all your events into a single stream, having them "marked" by `event_type`; `scan` on that stream with `[], []` as your initial state (no pending, nor active notifications yet); `if else if else` based on your `event_type` within the `scan` to compute next state correctly; take an outcome and render all active notifications.

---

From the comments:

> I still don't see how I manage the intervals in this solution. I mean, how do I move a notification from the pending to the active array, only after a set interval in which the currently active notification has been displayed.

Basically, two options. Since you're not strictly bound to a given limit for displaying some notification you can simply have global `interval` that emits, let's say, every `your_limit / 2` time units. Each notification you have may be extended with simple timestamp at the moment you move it to the list of active notifications. Next time your interval fires, you loop over that list and filter out all the notifications with time delta `>= your_limit`. That's a bit inaccurate, but can be easily configured and adjusted to be transparent for your users. I vote for this solutions for its simplicity.

The other solution is to fire `timer` per each notification once placed on the active list. Once timer done, you send an event `(notification_must_die, { notification_id: ... })` and your `scan` handles that; it must be prepared that such `notification_id` does not exist any more (it could be cancelled right before for example). It's complicated, but much more accurate.

Comment: Thanks @SerejaBogolubov, for simplicity , any chance you can show how this can be applied to the example in the sandbox I provided? (Replace the current `delay` in the `pipe` with the `scan` implementation)

Comment: @itaydafna it takes some time to implement, I'd rather suggest you try it yourself following my explanation and if you see any complications, you update your answer with the latest code and we see how to solve you problem.

Comment: I still don't see how I manage the intervals in this solution. I mean, how do I move a notification from the `pending` to the `active` array, only after a set interval in which the currently active notification has been displayed.

Comment: I've updated my question with an alternative solution I came up with which doesn't use `scan`. So the question now includes a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-q-68414582-my-non-operator-solution-3z4q8?file=/src/app/app.component.ts) of what I was trying to achieve. If you think this example could be better handled using `scan` I will be glad to hear. Thanks.